# Unable to resolve hostnames while using APT, what could be the problem?

Tags: 10.10, server, upgrade, dns

Until two days before today my Ubuntu 10.10 Server updated fine.

The output of `sudo aptitude update` **→** http://codepad.org/tkvXq66j

The output of `sudo aptitude update` after replacing the Ubuntu Central Archive's domain with the IP **→** http://codepad.org/QkgRhY8E

APT sources **→**  http://codepad.org/yh6E9TAe

Hosts **→** http://codepad.org/yODoWbHp

`/etc/resolv.conf` **→** http://codepad.org/Cba5kaEt

Comment: This is better suited for serverfault.com. Can you connect to the internet? What are the results of `ping http://example.com` and `curl http://example.com`?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Yes, -every- other Internet-requiring functions correctly. "ping: unknown host archive.ubuntu.com". I don't have curl installed, and due to this issue I can't install it via APT.

Comment: If `ping 8.8.8.8` works, it's a DNS issue. Otherwise, it's a problem in your network configuration. How can you run commands if you've no Internet connectivity?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: It's an oldie laptop on my LAN that I SSH into via PuTTY :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your network configuraton is broken. If you are using a static IP you must manually add the DNS servers to /etc/resolv.conf .
For example, to use google public dns service, append the following lines to the file.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

I am assuming that your IP network is properly configured and you can ping those IPs .

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it ! Yes, my network has DHCP Server in the modem/router but computers are given static IP.

Comment: It's actually better to use your ISP's DNS servers rather than Google's. For example, you'll most likely get better routing to things like Akamai's network by using your ISP's DNS.